# How to find expectation value of an operator for a given state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, wavefunction

> 31. The normalized wave functions $\Psi_1$ and $\Psi_2$ correspond to the ground state and the first excited states of a particle in a potential. The operators $\hat{A}$ act on the wave function as:
>       $$\hat{A}\Psi_1=\Psi_2\text{ and }\hat{A}\Psi_2=\Psi_1$$
>       The expectation value of the operator $\hat{A}$ for the state $\hat{A}=(3\Psi_1+4\Psi_2)/5$ is:
>       (A)  0
>       (B) -0.32
>       (C)  0.75
>       (D)  0.96

Not able to understand how to determine expectation value when ground state and first excited states are given.

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE!  Unfortunately, we have a policy against homework or "homework-like" questions here, so this question is likely to be closed as it stands. You might be able to avoid this if you provide more context about what you're already tried and what aspect of the problem you're confused about.

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the state is called $\hat A$ since $\hat A$ is also an operator, but if you call the state $|\psi\rangle$ such that $|\psi\rangle=(3|\psi_1\rangle+4|\psi_2\rangle)/5$ then the expectation value of $\hat A$ is given by
$$\langle\hat A\rangle=\langle\psi|\hat A|\psi\rangle$$
Since $\hat A$ is linear ( most quantum operators are linear) this can be expanded as follows:
$$\tfrac{1}{5}\left(3\langle\psi_1|+4\langle\psi_2|\right)\hat A\tfrac{1}{5}\left(3|\psi_1\rangle+4|\psi_2\rangle\right)=
\\\tfrac{1}{25}\left(9\langle\psi_1|\hat A|\psi_1\rangle+12\langle\psi_1|\hat A|\psi_2\rangle+12\langle\psi_2|\hat A|\psi_1\rangle+16\langle\psi_2|\hat A|\psi_2\rangle\right)$$
You can now replace $\hat A|\psi_1\rangle$ by $|\psi_2\rangle$ and $\hat A|\psi_2\rangle$ by $|\psi_1\rangle$.

What do you get as an expectation value now?

Hint: what are the values of $\langle\psi_1|\psi_1\rangle$, $\langle\psi_2|\psi_2\rangle$ and $\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle$?

Comment: Yeah that’s what I didn’t understand why is operator given as a combination of psi1 and psi2. After solving as you suggested the answer comes to 24/25 which is 0.96.